# How do you add an Icon to a WPF App?

Tags: wpf, icons

How do you add an Icon to a WPF App?

I have an icon made already.  How do I add it to the app so that it will represent the application on the desktop, in the minimize system bar, etc..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In my visual studio 2010 :
Project -> 'ApplicationName' Properties -> Tab Application -> Icon and Manifest. There you specify your icon

Comment: also remember to add the actual file to the project

Comment: I added it to my project but it doesn't show up when I run my application. It is saved though. Not sure why (I'm using VS2012).

Comment: You must add something like _Icon="icon.ico"_ to your _MainWindow.xaml_
<Window x:Class="WpfAppCertif_1.MainWindow"
...
mc:Ignorable="d"
Icon="icon.ico"
Title="MainWindow" Height="373" Width="635.119"
...
 DataContext="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyVM}"
 >